# Visualizing ACS PUMS data with weight / PWGTP

Tags: data-visualization, histogram, survey-weights, survey-sampling

I am working with American Census PUMS microdata, a yearly sample that includes a total weight per record and 80 replicate weights. I'm unsure if it makes sense to do descriptive statistics such as histograms, etc, using the unweighted data. Yet, if I'm to use the weights, I'm not sure how to account for the weights when making a simple plot.

For example, if I were to make a histogram in R, I might do:

```
qplot(factor(AGECAT), data, geom='bar', fill=factor(EDU))
```

How would I account for weights per row? I understand I could use the survey package to define the design and generate means and so forth, but I'm having a hard time connecting the dots.

Comment: This question seems clear enough to me. I'm voting to leave open.